# Error Parsing JSON in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, json, rubymotion

I'm trying to parse the following JSON:

```
"{\"name\":\"Damien\",\"message\":[\"Hi\"]}"
```

However, I've tried native parsing and Bubblewrap only to get the following error:

`-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98bde40
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98bde40'`

I've tried:

```
e = Pointer.new(:object)
json_hash = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json_string, options:0, error: e)
```

and

```
json_hash = BW::JSON.parse(json_string)
```

Both yield the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:' requires NSData object instead of String. You can convert from String to NSData using String#to_data

```
json_string = "{\"name\":\"Damien\",\"message\":[\"Hi\"]}"
e = Pointer.new(:object)
json_hash = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json_string.to_data, options:0, error: e)
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I did have to cast my string to an NSString first though:

e.g. `String(json_string).to_data`